# Change Body Background-Color on.Click to apply site-wide and on refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background-color

I would like to change the background-color of the body (and for a few modal elements) site-wide when a user toggles between two radios..

Here's the html for the radio buttons:

```
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default lightBtn">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="light"> Light
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default darkBtn">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="dark"> Dark
    </label>
  </div>
```

And the jquery that I've tried for the event, which has yet to change the background-color..

```
$( function() {
   $('#lightBtn').click( function() {
     $('body').css('background', 'white' );    
   });
   $('#darkBtn').click( function() {
     $('body').css('background', 'black' );    
   });
});
```

Also, the toggle on the btns resets from page to page.. is there jquery event language to maintain the toggle selection cross-page?

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20102750/change-background-color-using-radio-buttons

Comment: For your maintaining of the value through page refreshes, etc... you will have to set a cookie - jquery has a plugin for this: http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/ - or on github: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML defines `lightBtn` and `darkBtn` as classes (`.`) of your label elements, while your jQuery is targeting elements with the ID's `lightBtn` and `darkBtn` (`#`).

Change them to be the same, e.g:

```
$( function() {
   $('.lightBtn').click( function() {
     $('body').css('background', 'white' );    
   });
   $('.darkBtn').click( function() {
     $('body').css('background', 'black' );    
   });
});
```

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/F4z69/)

Or just change your HTML labels to be defined like:

`<label id="lightBtn" class="btn btn-default">` ...

`<label id="darkBtn" class="btn btn-default">` ...

Comment: Thanks for that.. the background-color resets from page to page though.. any way to maintain the selection?